# Idenitity between TD(0) algorithm and Policy Evaluation in Dynamic Programming when alpha is equal to 1

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dynamic-programming

TD(0) algorithm is defined as the iterative update of the following:

$$ V(s) \leftarrow V(s) + \alpha({r + \gamma V(s')} - V(s) ) $$

Now, if we assume alpha to be equal to 1, we get the traditional Policy Evaluation formula in Dynamic programming. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha$ is independent of the type of RL algorithm. It is the learning rate, i.e. the rate at which you will update a state value. You could set it to 1 or less.

Policy evaluation is a 'general principle'. Temporal difference is a way to make it work. More precisely, TD defines by **how far** in the future you take in account the consequences of an action. In your equation, gamma defines by **how much** you take that future into account.

Comment: Stop calling the learning rate as such. It is a step size, i.e. the fraction of a step taken toward the target. Learning rate as the name suggests, expresses a value of how the learning develops by some unit.

Comment: Policy evaluation is a framework for determining the value function of an MDP. You can plug many algorithms including but not confined to TD methods.

Answer (score 0):

No - Dynamic programming estimates the value of the next state by first looking at all possible next states. Temporal difference 0 estimates the value of the next state by only looking at a single next state.

Comment: Yes. This is one fundamental difference between the two methods. DP takes the expectation over all possible next states, TD is sampling one next state.